# How to recover passwords for all database schemas

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have installed Oracle 11g Express Edition and am using using SQL Developer.

I have created two schemas but forgotten the password - is there any way to unlock them?

Comment: 've u remember the password for sysdba?

Answer (score 2):

quite straightforward question....login as sysdba

```
sql>connect / AS sysdba
sql>alter user <use_name> identified by <Password>
ex:alter user xyz identified by stackover --don't enclose by quatos
```